# Preventing print dialog in .NET webbrowser control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have an application in vb.net/winforms with a WebBrowser control and navigate to a print preview of a website to generate a PDF of this website. But the page fires the default print dialog. This prevents full automating the application and cannot use network printers in the machines where the App execute.

How to navigate to this page without the print dialog?

I used the "scripterrorsupressed" but nothing happens.

I tried using the Httpwebrequest to bypass javascript, but this particular web site does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the WebBrowser control is, is basically a wrapper for Internet Explorer without the UI. It does not appear to have a way to suppress the dialog.

There are a couple of workarounds to possibly solve your issue.

### **Modify the source**

You could try to just get the HTML response and try to find where the print call is and remove it. Then load up the updated source (fixing URLs to absolute if needed) and load that into the Web Browser control. You may be able to also transform the [DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext(v=vs.110).aspx) as needed when the [Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated(v=vs.110).aspx) event fires.

### Disable the Print Dialog in Internet Explorer

Disabling the Print Dialog in Internet Explorer should also affect the Web Browser control. Results may differ depending on the version of Internet Explorer you are running.

[Click here for what I found in regards to IE8](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/24179d5f-d309-4caa-9d0c-48aa7f34f52f/disable-print-dialog-box?forum=ieitprocurrentver)

[Bunch of different registry settings for IE](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/442/)